# C# Ribbon сохранение и восстановление Quick Acces ToolBar item'ов

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

Я работаю с элементом Microsoft Ribbon WPF 2010.

У данного элемента есть *Ribbon Quick Access ToolBar*, в который, пользователь может добавлять элементы по мере работы в моем приложении.

Но, после перезапуска приложения все элементы из Ribbon Quick Access ToolBar обнуляются.

Я оставлю [ссылку](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Y-kXDskIVMdVEr5ETMtRLtsHZyTNwD2G) на проект Visual Studio 2010.

Кода очень много, поэтому я скажу что я уже добавил комманды (Command) для элементов, которые хочу добавлять в Ribbon Quick Access ToolBar

То есть, при работе пользователь может их добавлять. Как их после перезапуска обратно вернуть?

- обратите внимание на верхний левый угол - туда я добавил элементы.
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- ведь после перезапуска - они исчезают
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решить проблему?

Comment: Запомнить какие элементы добавил пользователь и добавить их при следующем запуске

Comment: именно это, да!"

Comment: Ну и в чем проблема?

Comment: Я же описал, не знаю как, я бы хотел увидеть код-сниппет для этого ибо сериализация не берёт тип данных ItemCollection(QuickAccessToolBar.Items)